# How do I remove a submodule from my github repository?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I happened to change a name of a directory within my local repository and then proceeded to push this change up to my github repository. In effect, it caused this repository to turn into a git submodule which is displayed as a green icon on github and there is no way to drill down further in to the directory to view individual files.

How do I remove the submodule from github?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the directory as file.

```
git rm --cached path/to/directory
```

Note that you don't use a trailing slash. This will delete the special file that point to the commmit in the subrepository.

Remove the .git folder inside the /path/to/directory before re-adding the directory into the index.

Comment: If I remove the .git folder will it automatically regenerate another .git folder when I go to commit? How does this work?

Comment: Nope, .git folders won't regenerate, but i think you got 2 .git folders, one in the root of your project and one in the "submodule" directory (this could also be a .git file) the last .git caused the directory to be added as submodule.